# mybatis column name with an underline

Tags: mysql, mybatis

is it a bug?
when I use mybatis and mysql, a column name id `permission_ids`, I got `null` always.
but when I change it to `permissions`, it worked. Why?

```
SELECT
    sys_role.id,
    sys_role.role,
    sys_role.description,
    sys_role.permission_ids
FROM sys_role
WHERE id = #{id}
```

Comment: What do you mean about you got `null` always?

Comment: maybe it should be `permission_id` (without the trailing `s`) ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XML file:

you should have:

```
<select  id="selectQuery" resultMap="selectMap">
    SELECT
        sys_role.id,
        sys_role.role,
        sys_role.description,
        sys_role.permission_ids
    FROM sys_role
    WHERE id = #{id}
</select>

<resultMap id="selectMap" type="SysRole">
   <id column="permission_ids" property="permissionIds">
   <result ....//the rest columns to map to java properties in your model class "SysRole"
</resultMap>
```

That should work !

If not, as an alternative to your solution, you can use Alias instead of renaming the column "permission_ids":

```
SELECT
    sys_role.id,
    sys_role.role,
    sys_role.description,
    sys_role.permission_ids **as permissions**
FROM sys_role
WHERE id = #{id}
```